# Antlr4 - Fix the grammar in order to match my internal language

Tags: antlr4

I have an internal language where I need to create a grammar in order to parse the language. But for some reason, I can not match the whole language.

The language is compund of those keywords:

```
$IF
$FROM
$THEN
$ANY
$EMPTY
$NOT
$COMPLEX
$COUNT
$COUNT_COMPLEX
```

The compiler unit or the simplest expression or statement has to follow this order:

```
$IF ... $FROM ... $THEN
```

I am able to match the majority of combinations. however, I can not match the list of values with space in the middle of any value like:

```
$IF Mechanical Instability,Deformity $FROM Type


grammar Trigger;

prog:   expr EOF;

expr

 :      IF (ANY|EMPTY|NOT|comparator|count|complex|count_complex|IDENTIFIER|LIST_VALUES) FROM IDENTIFIER THEN
 |      expr binary expr
 |      LPAREN expr RPAREN
 ;


comparator : (GT | GE | LT | LE | EQ)(INT|IDENTIFIER);

binary     : AND | OR;

count      : COUNT LPAREN (IDENTIFIER | DISTINCT) RPAREN comparator;
complex    : COMPLEX LPAREN expr RPAREN;
count_complex : COUNT_COMPLEX LPAREN (expr | DISTINCT IDENTIFIER expr) RPAREN comparator;

IF                   : '$IF';
FROM                 : '$FROM';
THEN                 : '$THEN';
AND                  : '$AND' ;
ANY                  : '$ANY';
EMPTY                : '$EMPTY';
DISTINCT             : '$DISTINCT';
COUNT                : '$COUNT';
COUNT_COMPLEX        : '$COUNT_COMPLEX';
COMPLEX              : '$COMPLEX';
OR                   : '$OR' ;
NOT                  : '$NOT' LPAREN CHAR+(',' CHAR)*? RPAREN;
GT                   : '>' ;
GE                   : '>=' ;
LT                   : '<' ;
LE                   : '<=' ;
EQ                   : '=' ;
LPAREN               : '(' ;
RPAREN               : ')' ;
INT                  : '-'?[0-9]+[0-9]*;
IDENTIFIER           : [a-zA-Z_.'0-9]+;
LIST_VALUES          : IDENTIFIER(',' IDENTIFIER)* ;
CHAR                 : [a-zA-Z_0-9];
WS                   : [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> skip;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your grammar `LIST_OF_VALUES` is a lexer rule, so a list of values would be recognized as a single token. Spaces (or rather skipped tokens in general) are only discarded between tokens not within one token. So if you want spaces to be discarded in the middle of something, you don't want that something to be a single token.

So instead of having a lexer rule `LIST_OF_VALUES`, you should have a parser rule `listOfValues` that consists of multiple identifier and comma tokens. Same for the parameter list of `$NOT`.

Comment: If you see I changed the grammar and now it is working for 95%. However,  I can not insert a free text in the middle of $IF and $FROM keywords. Ex:  $IF A B C $FROM xxxxx $THEN

Comment: @IuryRibeiro Why should `A B C` work? Nothing in your grammar expects anything like that. I thought you were asking why something like `A,B,C` can't have spaces after the commas. If you want `A B C` to work, you want to match `IDENTIFIER*` (or possibly a `*` after your whole sequence of alternatives, i.e. `(ANY|EMPTY|...|IDENTIFIER)*` - depends on what exactly you want to match and what you don't).